# how to send data from baseAdapter to Fragment and go to it in android?

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, android-listview, baseadapter

I tried this code to go to another fragment from the baseAdapter, but it didn't work for me. I got a lot of errors and I fixed them but now I am getting a new error which is --
The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Log)

I don't know how to fix this. I have searched a lot but could find no answer.
I'm using a listView inside a fragment and I want to go to another fragment when the item in this list is clicked and I want to pass data to the fragment as well.

```
 LogFrag fragment2 = new LogFrag();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment2);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the a sample code for that!

```
class TrackAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    Context context;

    public TrackAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.context = context;
    }



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final TrackAdapter proxy = this;
    final View trackView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    final TextView name = (TextView) trackView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context ,FRAGMENT_ACTIVITY.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

The most important part in the "FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" flag! It must be added for starting fragments!

Comment: But this is not applicable for fragments!!

Comment: why doesnt it work for you??? I myself have used it successfully!If it didn't help you, please post your logcat or explain more about what u exactly wanna do! @Jad Shd

Comment: it didn't work brcause you cannot open a fragment as activity without putting it in the manifest and you cannot do that because it is a fragment. I tried also to do a transaction but we cannot do that from the adapter!!